# Get Data From Datatables.net after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](http://datatables.net) to display some data. I also have inputs that are used to add a new row to the data. When I add this row, I reinitialise the table, and it automatically sorts the new row according to the sorting rules I give it. My question is this: Is there a way to get the data from the table in the order it's currently being viewed? Whenever I try
 `$('#tableCompetitors').dataTable().fnGetData()`, 
it gives me the data in the order it was added to the table not the ordered it's being presented in.

So is there an easy way to do what I want?

P.S. If it helps. The original datasource is an array of arrays that is provided from a textbox. I parse it, push it to an array, then use that array as the datasource.

Comment: if you save sort state would it matter what order data source is in?

Comment: What do you mean by save sort state? I need the data after it's sorted  so I can create a document structure based on the sorted data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one solution using 3 of the API callbacks.

1. Create variable for `CurrentData`
2. Reset `CurrentData` to empty array within `fnPreDrawCallback` which fires before the new table is rendered
3. `fnRowCallback` gives access to array of data for each row, push that array into `CurrentData` array
4. `fnDrawCallback` fires after table rendered, can now access sorted data in `CurrentData` array

JS

```
  var currData = [];
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "fnPreDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        /* reset currData before each draw*/
        currData = [];
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        /* push this row of data to currData array*/
        currData.push(aData);

    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        /* can now access sorted data array*/
        console.log(currData)
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ne24B/

Comment: This works. I'm going to wait and see if there are any other solutions offered before I accept it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I came across this with the same question.  While the accepted solution may work, I found a better way:

```
$("example").DataTable().rows({search:'applied'}).data()
```

See [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just trying to give you another option.

The following will get all the rows in the table, even if they are filtered out:

```
var currData = [];
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

oTable.$("tr").each(function(index, row){
    //generate your array here
    // like $(row).children().eq(0) for the first table column
    currData.push($(row).children().eq(0));
    // return the data in the first column
    currData.push($(row).children().eq(0).text());
});
```

or if you just want the results that match the filter then:

```
var currData = [];
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

oTable.$("tr", {"filter":"applied"}).each(function(index, row){
    //generate your array here
    // like $(row).children().eq(0) for the first table column
    currData.push($(row).children().eq(0));

    // return the data in the first column
    currData.push($(row).children().eq(0).text());
});
```

currData will contain the sorted list of the first column data.

Edit:
To get the entire row's text into the array.

```
$(row + " td").each(function(index, tdData){
    currData.push($(tdData).text());
});
```

or

```
$(row).children().each(function(index, tdData){
    currData.push($(tdData).text());
});
```

This way you have a little more control on what the array can contain. My 2 cents.

Comment: What does the the `$(row).children().eq(0)` return exactly? Is it an array containing the row data? I'd try it myself and find out, but I'm away from my development machine right now.

Comment: It returns the first column. If you want the data in the column you could `$(row).children().eq(0).text()`

Comment: I want the entire row as an array. Can I just do `$(row).text(), or some other similar voodoo? This code looks a bit cleaner so I'm tempted to explore it.

Comment: `$(row + " td").each(function(index, tdData){
currData.push($(tdData).text());
});`

Comment: or `$(row).children().each(function(index, tdData){
currData.push($(tdData).text());
});`